# Position of placeholder text in (multiline) TextInput for Android (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I've got a multi-line TextInput like so:

```
<TextInput
  multiline={true}
  placeholder='Enter description...'
  underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
>
```

On iOS it renders the ***placeholder*** text nicely per this screenshot.
[image]

On Android, it's putting the *placeholder* text as centered vertically! I've checked and there are no styles in any parent component that would force this behavior (again iOS is fine as per the screenshot).

Is there a way to justify that placeholder text to the top of the frame (same as iOS) ?
[image]

Comment: how did you make the your label blend nicely? can you share some code or gist you use :)

Comment: @WantIt I think it's basically borderless textbox inside a white bg with shadow and radius, where DESCRIPTION header is a part of that View

Answer (score 87, accepted):

got it, used this prop: textAlignVertical={'top'}

Comment: Worked on Android

Comment: Still getting same issue

Comment: Helped me very much!